# asp.net c# from server side lauch popup and wait for response before executing next line

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, modal-dialog

I want to launch a modal popup from c# code and wait for user to hit the ok button before executing the next c# line.

I tried the following

```
 System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", alertMessage, true);
```

but it does not pause to wait for use to hit the ok button and keeps going.

I also tried this

```
Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert( " + alertMessage + " );</script>");
```

But it returning an error message

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can't do that. All of the server side code is executed and then the entire html is sent to the client.

Comment: Yup, you may need to split your logic to move the `next line of C#` to your `button` click or another method that fires when that happen... or you could fire the popup from client side and have the logic to wait for the click there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a simple method on aspx page

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function openModal(id) {
            $(id).modal('show');
        }
    </script>
```

Then call this function in code like

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal('#yourModalID');", true);
```